# Captura de um valor utilizando Select com Django

Tags: django

Bom dia.
Criei um formulário e nele inseri os nomes dos meus clientes em um select. Ao selecionar um deles gostaria de real ziar um filtro, mas não está funcionando, parece que o valor do campo selecionado não está sendo enviado para a view.

Segue o código:

View

```
@login_required
def home_filtro(request):
    cliente = request.POST.get('cliente.id')
    atas = Ata.objects.filter(cliente=cliente)
    clientes = Cliente.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'core/index.html',
                  {'atas': atas, 'clientes': clientes)
```

HTML

```
<!--Filtros-->
<form action="{% url 'core_home_filtro' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="cliente_id">
              {% for cliente in clientes %}
                 <option value= "{{cliente.id}}" > {{cliente}} </option>
              {% endfor %}
      </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="mt-3 btn btn-primary">Filtrar</button>
</form>
```

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a enter o que está havendo?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se você alterar apenas a linha abaixo, veja se retorna algum erro.

```
if request.POST:
     cliente = request.POST['cliente.id']
```